# Why 厚かましい is not 厚がましい

Tags: words, etymology

I usually encounter adjectives of this form `adj+がましい` which means similar to `adj+らしい` based on my understanding. I recently discovered this word 厚かましい. I find it peculiar that it ends with かましい not がましい. Is there any reason for this oddity? Or maybe 厚かましい have no relation to がましい and it's just a coincidence?

Comment: がましい is added to a noun or a verb stem.

Comment: @aguijonazo Thanks, so it's a coincidence after all?

Comment: I can’t answer that. I just wanted to correct your formula. They may share an origin.

Comment: It seems 厚かましい, as well as やかましい, is related to [囂し](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/かまし). I couldn’t find a reference that says がましい is just the voiced (連濁) version of it but found this word [ことがまし](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/ことがまし) in 古語辞典, in which it carries a similar meaning to やかましい but is pronounced がまし.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because 厚か is the word with ましい is the stem - so か is not being used as a substitute for the が particle. I could be wrong